# I want to gernate pdf preview in flutter from network url but not finding any way to achieve this

Tags: flutter, pdf

this is the code

FutureBuilder(
future: DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(
'https://github.com/espresso3389/flutter_pdf_render/raw/master/example/assets/hello.pdf'),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
print('data in snapshot is ${snapshot.data}');
return snapshot.hasData
? Container(
height: 4.h,
width: 20.w,
child: PdfThumbnail.fromFile(snapshot.data!.path, currentPage: 0,
backgroundColor:
Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3),
height: 200,

```
                /// You can put widget to display page number.
                /// This widget will be in stack.
                currentPageWidget: (page, isCurrentPage) {
                  return Positioned(
                    bottom: 50,
                    right: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      color: isCurrentPage ? Colors.green : Colors.pink,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        '$page',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },

                /// Customize decoration so selected page is highlighted
                currentPageDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),),)
                : Container(child: Center(child: Text('no data found...',style: AppStyle.lightDarkTextStyle,)),);
          }
        ),
```

Thing i tried:
use pdf_thumnail package
use pdf_rendere with cache_pdf
no solution work for me

i just want to show thumbnail of firstpage in a widget

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to pdf preview from url

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview

And use this code to preview pdf on your view

```
const PDF(
            ).cachedFromUrl(
             strURL,
              placeholder: (progress) => Center(child: Text('$progress %')),
              errorWidget: (error) => Center(child: Text(error.toString())),
            )
```